# Why do I have 2 classes named Fragment in eclipse?

Tags: android

I am trying to write class that extends `Fragment`, and I see one class `Fragment` from, what are the differences and which one should I use ?

> adt-bundle-windows/x86.../sdk/platforms/android-19, and one from android-support-v4

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Fragment`s have been introduced in Android 3.0 (API 11). But Google made available a compatibility `Fragment` for older android versions. So if you're targeting devices below API 11, you should use the `Fragment`s from the compatibility library in your project.

Comment: which one is the compatibility ? and it is not the same as the new one ?

Comment: @shd : The compatibility one is the v4 which denotes API 4. In other words it means anything in the v4 library is compatible with devices running Android v1.6 (API 4) onwards. The difference between the two is that devices running later versions of Android have native support for the various classes but the compatibility libraries are 'static' and will be packaged with your Android APK.